# Handling a lot of user files

Tags: php, performance, file-upload

I've heard that in Linux, you should keep you directories below 32000 files in one folder. That's why I want to make an upload directory, that's build like this:

```
$x = rand(0,32000);
$z = rand(0,32000);
$y = rand(0,32000);
$f = rand(0,32000);

root/uploaddir/$x/$y/$z/$f/{user_id}/
```

My problem is, that I also want to check, if it already exists and if it does want to check if there already is 32000 in the directory.

But when I get to have 30000^4 directories I don't know how I should handle it, so it doesn't get too slow.

So how should I perform a check on and find what directory a file should be placed in, when the parameter is:
 - Folder and parent folders must not have more 32.000 files/directories

Hope it is understandable.

Best Regards,

Denlau.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using random numbers, use consecutive characters from the userid:

```
/root/uploaddir/j/o/n/e/jones/
/root/uploaddir/s/m/i/t/smith
/root/uploaddir/f/r/e/d/freddie
etc.
```

Then you'll never have more than about 200 entries in each directory.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to have 32000^4 possible directories :)

Comment: That's over 10^18. Do you need a separate directory for every grain of sand on the earth?

Comment: Just because it says you should keep the number under 32000, it doesn't mean it's a good idea to go up to that many. Scanning huge directories is really slow.

Comment: Well, it's folders, that users can upload pictures corresponding to their advertisements. And I just wanted to not bump in to any boundries later on - so the 32000^4 is only for keeping my options open. I will only use one directory until it's "full" before I create another.. :)

Comment: The directory structure you showed in the question is just for getting to the userid's directory, not for organizing the contents of that directory. And unless you have billions of users, you don't need to worry about the containing directories getting too big.

Comment: Unless you're creating new Instagram like website you will not be bounded by that, I think? Why not just structure it based on username or userid?

Comment: Okay, well.. As I've read around the web that would give some issues, when I would get to 32.001 users - because a folder can only container 32.000 directories/files, before getting slow/buggy? Am I totally wrong about that? :)

Comment: Only if you have 32,000 users whose names begin with the same 4 letters.

Comment: I've added a little more detail to the answer, maybe you didn't understand what I was suggesting before.

Comment: Thus, it wouldn't be possible!

Comment: Well, if we say, that each letter is represented the same amount of times, that would give 20 billion possibilities. Should be secure enough for "big data".. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether a file or directory exists:

```
if( file_exists($path) ) {
    // do something here
}
```

[PHP: file_exists - Manual](https://www.php.net/file_exists)

Get number of files in the directory:

```
exec("ls $path | wc -l", $number_of_files);
```

[PHP: exec - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)